El programador de tareas no me ejecuta script .bat
Tengo un script .bat que me hace una tarea de mover unos archivos a una carpeta. Si la ejecuto desde el terminal de windows "cmd" o desde un "Acceso directo" funciona perfecto.
Pero si la tarea la tengo programada con el "Programador de Tareas" a una hora para que me la haga cada día no funciona. No llega a lanzar la tarea nunca.
He mirado el servicio del "Programador de Tareas" la opción en pestaña "Iniciar sesión" y activar donde dice "Permitir que el servicio interactúe con el escritorio" pero esa opción siempre me aparece bloqueada. Windows tampoco  me deja parar el servicio para ver si se desbloquea esa opción para luego activarla. He probado como cuenta de usuario administrador y siempre me sale bloqueada.


Cómo lo configuraste?

@Mateo Creo que se puede configurar en linea de comandos con schtasks.exe pero lo hice con el menu de el "Programador de Tareas". En pestaña "General"- Ejecutar tanto si el usuario inicio sesion como si no. En pestaña "Desencadenadores" Diariamente a una hora en concreto.  En pestaña "Acciones" puse accion = Iniciar un programa, en programa o script entre comillas "D:\miruta\miscript.bat". Aqui no se si tendria que poner mejor entre comillas "cmd.exe D:\miruta\miscript.bat".  Delas veces que lo he intentado el reultado de la ejecucion ha sido (0x1)

Entonces la tarea se ejecuta pero no correctamente?

@Mateo he conseguido que el programador de Tareas se active a la hora indicada pero el script que debe lanzar no llega a lanzarse. Si pongo cmd.exe como script y luego en la casilla de a agregar argumentos "miscript.bat" parece que ejecuta el cmd.exe pero no lanza miscript.bat y se queda en estado ejecucion sin terminar...

La solución es que tenia que hacer dos cosas importantes.
Primero hay que dar permisos a la cuenta que utilizo para lanzar la ejecución con el privilegio "Iniciar sesión como trabajo por lotes".
Esto se hace ejecutando "SecPol.msc" y en "póliticas locales" agregar el usuario  en "Asignación de derechos de usuario"
Segundo cosa importante es que si quiero lanzar un script .bat se debe hacer dentro de la pestaña "Acciones" e ir a "Iniciar programa" escribiendo  en el campo "Detalles" lo siguiente:
cmd.exe /c "D:\Directorio\MiScript.bat"

Importante que dentro de MiScript.bat si hay alguna otra ruta todas las rutas vengan escritas completamente con su directorio.
